# Verifying a solution for the differential equation $(D-m)^3y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Verify that $y=c_1e^{mx}+c_2xe^{mx}+c_3x^2e^{mx}$ satisfies the differential equation $(D-m)^3y=0$.

$(D= {d\over dx})$

I solved this problem, but our professor said that it was wrong because my method is not general and it is for a specific case, but I failed to understand what is wrong here, can someone please explain why?
Here is my professor's explanation:

"You need show that in general. This method is not general. It is for a specific case"

Here is what I did:

I substituted given $y$ into the differential equation, then proved it is equal to zero. Consider,

$$(D-m)^3(c_1e^{mx}+c_2xe^{mx}+c_3x^2e^{mx})=(D-m)^3c_1e^{mx}+(D-m)^3xc_2e^{mx}+(D-m)^3x^2c_3e^{mx}$$

then I used the fact that $F(D) e^{ax}V(x) =  e^{ax}F(D+a)V(x)$ :

$$(D-m)^3(c_1e^{mx}+c_2xe^{mx}+c_3x^2e^{mx})=e^{mx}(D)^31+e^{mx}(D)^3x+e^{mx}(D)^3x^2$$
$$e^{mx}(D)^3+e^{mx}(D)^3x+e^{mx}(D)^3x^2  = e^{mx}(D^31)+e^{mx}(D^3x)+e^{mx}(D^3x^2)=0$$

Thus:
$$(D-m)^3(c_1e^{mx}+c_2xe^{mx}+c_3x^2e^{mx})=0$$

Then I said that $y=c_1e^{mx}+c_2xe^{mx}+c_3x^2e^{mx}$ satisfies the differential equation $(D-m)^3y=0$.

Please explain, is it incorrect?

Thank you!

Comment: Your expression $(D)^3$ makes no sense on the first line of the computation. Of course, you meant $D^3(1)$. If your professor allows you to use "the fact" you quoted, then it seems fine, although I would state that I'm applying it with $F(t)=(t-m)^3$ and $a=m$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Is there something wrong in my method?

Comment: Other than your writing $(D)^3$ lots of places where it should be $D^3(1)$, as I already said, it seems fine to me. You should ask your professor what he doesn't like about it. Of course your professor gave you a specific problem and, aside from the issue I raised, you did it correctly, so I don't know what he means by "not general."

Comment: @TedShifrin now see my problem